# MongoDB - Add to set, add new array with values

Tags: php, mongodb

Hi I want to be able to add new arrays inside of arrays in Mongo, I want a structure like this -

[image]

The part im interested in is 'AutoFix' down. Instead of `0:NULL` I want it to be `autofix: (blank)` for example if it wasn't blank it would be

```
AutoFix

   Kieron Bramley

       autofix               One
       autofix               Two
```

My code so far...

```
    $search = array(
      '_id' => new MongoId($_POST['ruleID'])
    );
    $collection->update(
       $search, 
       array('$push' => 
         array("AutoFix.".$value[0], 
           "autofix" => "")
       ), 
       array('upsert' => true)
     );
```

`$value[0]` is for example Kieron Bramley each one of these is its own array so there could be another John Doe.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in the update part of your query. In Mongo console you'd write `{ "$push": { "Autofix.someKey": { "autofix": "" } } }` and to translate this to PHP:

```
array(
    '$push' => array("AutoFix.".$value[0] => array("autofix" => ""))
)
```